How to fix error WITH query ... has 1 columns available but 2 columns specified
I would like to do two consecutive inserts and in the second insert I want to use data which is the result of the first insert.
I tried this:
drop table if exists persons cascade;
create table persons (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null);
drop table if exists accounts cascade;
create table accounts (
  id serial primary key,
  login text not null,
  owner int not null references persons(id));
with
  people (name, login) as (
    values
    ('Alice', 'ali'),
    ('Bob',   'bob')),
  owners (id, name) as (
    insert into persons (name)
    select p.name from people p
    returning (id, name))
insert into accounts (login, owner)
select (people.login, owners.id)
from people
join owners using (name);
select * from persons;
select * from accounts;

But I get the error:

ERROR:  WITH query "owners" has 1 columns available but 2 columns specified
LINE 6:   owners (id, name) as (
          ^


What does this mean? How to fix the problem?

I think you need to use returning id, name, not returning (id, name) (one is two columns, the other is a single column with a row value/composite value).

@MarkRotteveel Thanks but there was also another error.

This works:
drop table if exists persons cascade;
create table persons (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null);
drop table if exists accounts cascade;
create table accounts (
  id serial primary key,
  login text not null,
  owner int not null references persons(id));
with
  people (name, login) as (
    values
    ('Alice', 'ali'),
    ('Bob',   'bob')),
  owners (id, name) as (
    insert into persons (name)
    select p.name from people p
    returning id, name) -- wrong: returning (id, name))
insert into accounts (login, owner)
select people.login, owners.id -- wrong: select (people.login, owners.id)
from people
join owners using (name);
select * from persons;
select * from accounts;


You may want to explicitly mention what you changed
